# E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-old-releases Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, software-sources

When I use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I got the following errors.

```
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-old-releases Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried a few solutions but seems that they did not work for my system. I don't know how to update `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic) is not an old-release (ie. it's currently supported and not EOL - old-releases is for EOL releases).  You need to change `old-releases.ubuntu.com` to 'archive.ubuntu.com`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic from 2018-April thus 18.04) is not an old-release, ie. it's currently supported and not EOL (`old-releases` is for EOL releases).

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has 5 years of standard support so is supported until 2023-April, then moves to ESM or extended support before finally having it's repositories moved from `archive.ubuntu.com` to where you're file is looking - `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

You need to change `old-releases.ubuntu.com` to `archive.ubuntu.com` for that entry in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file