# Missing Libcrypto.so.1.0.0 Library

Tags: 20.04, libraries, shared-library

I'm trying to deploy a game from Gamemaker Studio 1.4 to Ubuntu Studio 20.04 and I'm missing some libraries. I've tried contacting the forum for that [here](https://forum.yoyogames.com/index.php?threads/cant-properly-deploy-gamemaker-studio-1-4-game-from-windows-to-linux.75974/), but no luck probably because the program wants an older library, and that's a problem caused by Linux. I think I have newer versions of the libraries (libcrypto.so and libssl.so), but the program requires the older versions (libcrypto.so.1.0.0 and libssl.so.1.0.0). I have libcrypto.so.1.1 and tried symlinking it to the /usr/lib folder using ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0. It works, but now I had to do the same with libssl. That worked. Now, I'm getting the error in the screenshot.

[image: after linking libcrypto and libssl]

I tried tampering with the library files, but it ended up causing a kernel panic. Fortunately, I image my system before messing with stuff like that. Any idea how to fix these errors or a better way to use older libraries as the program I'm using requires them?

Thanks.

Comment: here is a solution: [works for Ubuntu 20.04](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283607/libraries-libcrypto-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-d)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it looks like you missed installing libssl1.0.0:i386 (which includes libcrypto.so.1.0.0).  And/or installed libssl-dev:i386 when not doing YYC builds, which will redirect the 1.0 ssl files to 1.1 files on later versions of Ubuntu, or something like that.  I can't say I remember all the nuances exactly.

I ran into the same thing on Mint 19 and just spent a hard week working it all out.  It's too long to put here so I threw it to a blog post [here](https://namethattech.wordpress.com/2020/09/04/from-gamemaker-to-ubuntu-14-16-18-and-beyond/) .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's been a while since I've responded. I just haven't had a chance to mess around with this until recently. What juanitogan mentioned is what the issue was, but I tried that following the original instructions and it wasn't letting me because `libssl-1.0.0` was obsolete or something. Since it didn't let me do that, I ended up installing `libssl-1.1` instead, but GameMaker requires `libssl-1.0.0` instead, so that's where my problem was. It also wasn't letting me install `lib32ncurses5`, so I was doing `lib32ncurses6` instead. That's why I did `libssl-1.1` and tried symlinking *libcrypto* to 1.0.0 to attempt tricking it, but it produced the error in the screenshot.

I had another go at it recently, and was able to do it by modifying the list of apt sources to include *archive.ubuntu* related stuff in `/etc/apt/sources.list` ([website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188970/e-the-repository-http-old-releases-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-bionic-old-releases-rel)), which didn't quite fix it yet. I did what the solution of the linked site showed. I also had to add "public keys" or something like that in the following format: `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys (a key listed in the output)`. [This](https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/) is the site referenced. I ran the command twice adding two different keys that were listed in the output of trying to install I believe, running the command with one key at a time. I forget exactly what I did, but I live-streamed the process of trying to fix all the issues [here](https://youtu.be/5dlSenIcGg8?t=10215). I start actually figuring stuff out around 2:50:15, which the link should bring you to. If you watch, feel free to skim around after that area if you want to see exactly what happened. The source you see at that moment (2:50:15) is the very first thing I've tried since originally asking the question basically. I was setting everything up again and getting to this phase before that.

I knew I would need to do this eventually, so I tried figuring it out ahead of time in case I would have to ask a question since I know it can take a while for someone to respond with an answer, especially if it's technical like this. I didn't need to do this right away, but I knew I eventually would, so I planned ahead so I would be all ready when the time came. I appreciate you answering and bearing with me! Thanks a lot.